# WebGL publisher not listed in unity registry of package manger in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

So I am following a 2-week course from unity for starter, and in here one mission we are supposed to build a game using WebGL builder and WebGL publisher package, now its asks me to check if webGL publisher package is already installed or not and if not then install it.

Now to install it, the WebGL publisher package should be in the unity registry of the package manager, but in my case there is nothing. plz help me

[image]

my unity version is 2020.1.6f1, what should i do now

Comment: In the advanced drop down menu of the package manager window select "show preview packages". That will allow you to view and install the WebGl Publisher package. See this thread: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1722568/share-webgl-game-is-not-found-in-package-manager.html

Comment: @EaswarChinraj as you can see in my screenshot, it is already showing preview packages and i have turned it on, and also checked it twice, 
what if it is moved somewhere else like now you are not required to install it now seprately in packages

Comment: You can install version 2019.6.1 in Unity Hub. I solved the same problem in this version. In other versions like 2020.1 or 2019.4.11 or 2018.4 i didn't find WebGL publisher too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the developer of the WebGL Publisher.
The Package has always been there, it's just that it wasn't visible for some internal reasons in 2020 releases, so you needed to add it manually to your manifest file. This has been fixed, and the package is now searchable from the package Manager.

[image: Package manager screenshot]

You can use it for any Unity version that is above Unity 2019.3 (including 2021).

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, according to what I've found, WebGL publisher is yet to come to unity 2020. so if you absolutely need this package I recommend downgrading to unity 2019